# What does the OpenVPN 'auth' directive do?

Tags: vpn, security, openvpn, authentication, cryptography

What does the 'auth' directive do in an OpenVPN config file?

I am using a PKI system with my OpenVPN setup, as detailed [here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/EasyRSA3-OpenVPN-Howto), and i have got everything working OK (I.E Client connects to server). However, nowhere in my configuration file for server or client have i used the 'auth' directive. I have seen in other people's config files things like this:

`auth SHA512`

Do i need to be using this directive? What does OpenVPN default to if i do not specify it?

Sorry, i am a bit new to cryptography, PKI's etc, and want to harden my OpenVPN server as much as possible. Please do point out any other improvements i should make!

EDIT:

This is my server config:

```
port 23535
proto udp4
dev tun
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Keys\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Keys\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Keys\\server.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Keys\\dh2048.pem"
tls-crypt-v2 "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\Keys\\server-tls-crypt-v2.key"
topology subnet
server 10.43.166.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
cipher AES-256-GCM
status openvpn-status.log
verb 4
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

and my client config:

```
setenv FRIENDLY_NAME "Test VPN."
client
dev tun
proto udp4
remote vpn.server.local 23535
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-GCM
verb 4
mute-replay-warnings


<ca>
REDACTED
</ca>

<cert>
REDACTED
</cert>

<key>
REDACTED
</key>

<tls-crypt-v2>
REDACTED
</tls-crypt-v2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The
[Reference manual for OpenVPN 2.4](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/)
defines the `auth` parameter, which overrides this same parameter
in the config file, as follows:

> **--auth alg**
>
> Authenticate data channel packets and (if enabled) tls-auth control
> channel packets with HMAC using message digest algorithm alg. (The
> default is SHA1 ). HMAC is a commonly used message authentication
> algorithm (MAC) that uses a data string, a secure hash algorithm, and
> a key, to produce a digital signature. The OpenVPN data channel
> protocol uses encrypt-then-mac (i.e. first encrypt a packet, then HMAC
> the resulting ciphertext), which prevents padding oracle attacks.

As regarding setting this value to SHA512, rather than the default SHA1,
this is answered in the post
[OpenVPN using SHA1 instead of SHA512](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=31534)
by user TinCanTech  :

> Just so you understand, using SHA512 is wasting CPU cycles on your VPN nodes.

SHA1 is the default, as it is regarded as secure enough.
Message authentication is not as critical as, for example,
when exchanging digital certificate keys.

Comment: Thanks! If i wanted to use SHA256 to be a tiny bit overkill, would i put the auth directive in the server or client config file, or both?

Comment: I believe it's rather a client parameter.

Comment: @M_D I'm quite sure that the parameter must be in sync between the client and the server. It works as default to `SHA1` because I think that is the default in servers and clients.